# Eclipse won't build project with XML errors

Tags: xml, eclipse, compiler-construction, build

I have recently switched from Netbeans to Eclipse.  I have a project which contains a syntactically incorrect XML file which is used for Unit Testing.  The project then has a red exclamation mark over it, and when you expand the hierarchy the XML file is the only node which displays this icon.

It appears my project is not building due to this.  Is there a setting somewhere that I can change so it doesn't get prevented by this XML file?

Comment: What if you remove that file from your workspace, is building possible then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your XML validation configuration here: `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `XML` -> `XML Files` -> `Validation`.

But this shouldn't be that restrictive by default to make your project couldn't be build.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to:

- Customize and fine-tune validation options located in **Window ->
  Preferences -> Validation** -> **XML**
- Delete particular errors from **Problems** view (they will reapper
  during the next clean/build of your project)